# NSTableCellView and NSArrayController - Mac OSX

Tags: macos, nstableview, nsarraycontroller, nstablecellview

Is it possible to bind a NSArraycontroller with NSTableView whose cells are not text cells but nstablecellview? I'm new to cocoa programming, tried searching on this but no proper explanation on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can set the NSTableView to View based.
Instead of binding to the column, bind the cell UI element (e.g. NSTextField) to the "Table Cell View" using objectValue.propertyName

Ref:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/PopulatingViewTablesWithBindings/PopulatingView-TablesWithBindings.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21752/how-to-use-cocoa-bindings-and-core-data-in-a-mac-app

Comment: It's not necessary to use value transformers.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't figure `objectValue.something.something` would suffice and tried other ways until you simply said so. Works.